# How safe is unsafe cast when it is checked by type_id?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I have an enum called Magnitude:

```rust
pub enum Magnitude<T> {
    /// A finite value
    Finite(T),

    /// Positive infinity
    PosInfinite,

    /// Negative infinity
    NegInfinite,
}
```

and I want to implement `From` trait to be able to construct Magnitude from different types:

```rust
impl<T: Any> From<T> for Magnitude<T> {
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        if value.type_id() == TypeId::of::<f64>() {
            unsafe {
                let value_f64 = (&value as *const T).cast::<f64>().as_ref().unwrap().clone();
                if  value_f64 == f64::INFINITY {
                    Magnitude::PosInfinite
                } else if value_f64 == f64::NEG_INFINITY {
                    Magnitude::NegInfinite
                } else {
                    Magnitude::Finite(value)
                }
            }
        } else if value.type_id() == TypeId::of::<f32>() {
            unsafe {
                let value_f32 = (&value as *const T).cast::<f32>().as_ref().unwrap().clone();
                if  value_f32 == f32::INFINITY {
                    Magnitude::PosInfinite
                } else if value_f32 == f32::NEG_INFINITY {
                    Magnitude::NegInfinite
                } else {
                    Magnitude::Finite(value)
                }
            }
        } else {
            Magnitude::Finite(value)
        }
    }
}
```

if `value` is checked to be of type `f64` using `type_id`, how unsafe is it to cast it to f64?

it passes the test below but I don't know if it will work correctly all the time:

```rust
#[test]
fn f64_infinity() {
    let pos_inf: Magnitude<f64> = f64::INFINITY.into();
    let neg_inf: Magnitude<f64> = f64::NEG_INFINITY.into();

    assert!(pos_inf.is_pos_infinite());
    assert!(neg_inf.is_neg_infinite());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but can't you use the `downcast_ref` method from `Any`? It seems more appropriate and does not need `unsafe`.

Comment: @NiklasMohrin The `downcast_ref()` and `downcast_mut()` methods are for dynamic downcasting at runtime. They are only implemented for trait objects of type `dyn Any + 'static` and similar, but not for concrete types implenting the `Any` trait.

Comment: @NiklasMohrin If I'm not mistaken, `downcast_ref` is implemented for `dyn Any` which means I have to implement `From<dyn Any>` instead of `From<T>`. but `From` is bounded by `Sized` trait which `dyn Any` does not implement because its size can not be known at compile time.

Comment: Right, that checks out! Coming back to your question: I looked at the source of `downcast_ref` and there they are casting pointers after comparing type ids as well (https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/any.rs.html#195-204). You should be good

Comment: @NiklasMohrin that looks promising! I wonder if this `if type_check then cast` is correct, can rust have something like smart cast in kotlin...

Answer (score 3):

A more natural way of implementing what you want would be to write different implementations for different types:

```
impl From<f32> for Magnitude<f32> {
    fn from(value: f32) -> Self {
        if value == f32::INFINITY {
            Magnitude::PosInfinite
        } else if value == f32::NEG_INFINITY {
            Magnitude::NegInfinite
        } else {
            Magnitude::Finite(value)
        }
    }
}
```

However, it would be difficult to implement a blanket implementation if you already have concrete implementations

```
impl<T> From<T> for Magnitude<T> {
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        Magnitude::Finite(value)
    }
}
```

results in

```
conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<f32>` for type `Magnitude<f32>`:
  --> src/lib.rs:22:1
   |
10 | impl From<f32> for Magnitude<f32> {
   | --------------------------------- first implementation here
...
22 | impl<T> From<T> for Magnitude<T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Magnitude<f32>`
```

While there is [an accepted RFC to support specialization in Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), this has not yet been fully implemented. For the time being, I suggest a slightly less general approach:

```
macro_rules! magnitude_from_float_impl {
    ($t:ty) => {
        impl From<$t> for Magnitude<$t> {
            fn from(value: $t) -> Self {
                if value.is_infinite() {
                    if value.is_sign_positive() {
                        Magnitude::PosInfinite
                    } else {
                        Magnitude::NegInfinite
                    }
                } else {
                    Magnitude::Finite(value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! magnitude_from_impl {
    ($t:ty) => {
        impl From<$t> for Magnitude<$t> {
            fn from(value: $t) -> Self {
                Magnitude::Finite(value)
            }
        }
    }
}


magnitude_from_float_impl!(f32);
magnitude_from_float_impl!(f64);
magnitude_from_impl!(i64);
magnitude_from_impl!(i32);
```

This does not provide a blanket implementation, but it's easy to add further types to the list of supported types.

Comment: It's a good solution but it's more complicated and hefty than one block of the unsafe cast. Of course, all that is true **if** that type of cast I mentioned is safe. if it's not safe, your solution is the way to go. That's why I'm curious and worried! about the safety of the mentioned cast

Comment: Your cast is fine – it's just more complex than it needs to be. `let value_f64 = *(&value as *const T as *const f64);` is more concise and readable in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @SvenMarnach for your help :). Yes, yours is much more readable! I will use it instead